# React-native lifecycle methods warning: " componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version"

Tags: react-native, remote-debugging

While using the life-cycle methods in react-native, I have encountered the following warning messages in the console as well as in the emulator:

> Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. Use static getDerivedStateFromProps instead.
>
> Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary workaround, you can rename to UNSAFE_componentWillMount.

The warnings are even displayed annoyingly in the emulator as follows: 
[image: Warning messages in the Emulator]

The problem arises whenever i dismiss the warning messages in the emulator, the application crashes, hence i have to restart the application again.
What can I do about this?

Also, despite the warning messages, I have never used the method "componentWillReceiveProps". However, I have made use of the method "componentWillMount". What could be the cause of receiving warning message even related to method "componentWillReceiveProps"?

Comment: You omitted the single piece of information in the alert that would give you more info..... the [url](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/6)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it does not affect your application, it's just annoying.

Hide it by add below into `index.js`:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  'Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated',
  'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated',
  'Module RCTImageLoader requires',
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

These deprecation notices was not due to land in React Native 0.54 but was by mistake, you can upgrade React Native to 0.54.1 and see that these messages are gone.

Read more [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18175).

Comment: how do you actually do the upgrade correctly to 0.54.1?

Comment: nevermind, just changed it in package.json to 0.54.1, not sure if this is best way as I saw a git method as well.

Comment: I just added the method mentioned above in my index.js file and it worked for me! for now! Not a permanent solution though. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { ... }`

with

`static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) { ... }`

and use `prevState` as your current state.

remember, this method should return an object to update the state or null to update nothing and doesn't have access to the component instance. something like redux.
see [this](https://itnext.io/react17-or-how-to-get-rid-of-componentwillreceiveprops-c91f9a6f6f03)